# Enabling 'New Organisation' button for Current Employer field in View Contact

Tags: contacts, relationships

We recently upgraded to CiviCRM 4.7.19 on Drupal 7.52 and for some reason the New Organization button isn't appearing when searching for an unknown organization for a contact's current employer. I can add an organization via CiviCRM > Contacts > New Organisation but our backoffice staff liked being able to add from the person contact page. I've checked the console and there are no errors flagged and isn't a CSS thing as the element holding the button exists but just doesn't have the button markup e.g. instead of:

```
<div class="crm-entityref-links"> <a class="crm-add-entity crm-hover-button" href="/civicrm/profile/create?reset=1&amp;context=dialog&amp;gid=5"><i class="crm-i fa-building"></i> New Organization</a></div>
```

the page only has:

```
<div class="crm-entityref-links"></div>
```

I've checked permissions and as far as I can tell everything is set ok. Is there a setting I'm missing?

[image]

**Update**

Looking at our l10n-js file I can see that the `contactCreate` object is not being populated:

```
CRM.config.entityRef = $.extend({}, {"contactCreate":[]...
```

Digging into the code I can see this is supposed to be created in Core/Resources.php ([line 685](http://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/d90703e148682e062df9dbdb491225af195f8a51/CRM/Core/Resources.php#L685)):

```
'contactCreate' => CRM_Core_BAO_UFGroup::getCreateLinks()
```

Looking at CRM/Core/BAO/UFGroup.php I can see the [`getCreateLinks()` function](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/1f8e8d5a574f705bd128a507d98f804a557e05cb/CRM/Core/BAO/UFGroup.php#L3300) calls

```
public static function getCreateLinks($profiles = '', $appendProfiles = array()) {
    // Default to contact profiles
    if (!$profiles) {
      $profiles = array('new_individual', 'new_organization', 'new_household');
    }
    $profiles = (array) $profiles;
    $toGet = array_merge($profiles, (array) $appendProfiles);
    $retrieved = civicrm_api3('uf_group', 'get', array(
      'name' => array('IN' => $toGet),
      'is_active' => 1,
    ));
```

Running a similar API call on our install:

```
$result = civicrm_api3('UFGroup', 'get', array(
  'sequential' => 1,
  'name' => array('IN' => array("new_individual", "new_organization")),
));
```

I get no results, the reason is because the name is actually `new_organization_5` not `new_organization` Still don't know how to fix

Comment: On my copy (running the master branch) I can create a new organization from this widget (while logged in as an administrator).  I know that doesn't solve your problem but hopefully it's helpful!

Comment: can see it working on http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/ as well .. still not sure why are install is missing this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you discovered, the system expects to have 3 reserved profiles: "new_individual", "new_organization" and "new_household". If you accidentally deleted or renamed those profiles (machine "name" field not the user-facing title) I suggest naming them back, or else creating new ones with those names.

Comment: Excellent - I've been struggling for months to work out why one of my sites was manifesting this issue. Now I've finally fixed it. I guess the next question is how a reserved profile got deleted.