# Add New Organization Option to Public Autocomplete Extension

Tags: extension, autocomplete

Hey everyone we've just installed the public autocomplete extension https://civicrm.org/extensions/public-autocomplete-of-organisation-names but are having some difficulty getting it to "add new" or the "new organization" button to display (as it does when logged in as admin, editing a record and selecting "Current Employer") while also still creating the Employer-Employee relationship

(this is for anon users) also we'd like to restrict the list that displays by group and contact type

in other words, create new org similar to webform-civicrm or within civicrm.

trying acls, adding code per the video athttps://civicrm.org/extensions/public-autocomplete-of-organisation-names

but nothing works yet.

We are using civicrm 4.7 so any thoughts or feedback , greatly appreciated!

H

p.s. similar maybe not identical to [Enabling 'New Organisation' button for Current Employer field in View Contact](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/18658/enabling-new-organisation-button-for-current-employer-field-in-view-contact)

Comment: Did you read instructions at https://github.com/TechToThePeople/publicautocomplete? Have you set the "access AJAX API" permission?

Comment: Thanks Pete, that helped and it is suggesting. Weird tho as the auto-complete still has too many orgs in the drop down, regardless of spelling. 
So we're also going to try installing the quick auto-complete. Best civi auto-suggest mechanism we have observed  is either 1. Current Employer - edit within civi contact, allows 'New Org"  and  2. when entering an activity where "With Contact" cleanly suggests, restricts, then accepts the entry or provides for "New Organization."We're trying to create something similar for user registration at civicrm/profile/create?gid=1&reset=1.

Comment: Hi Hardwick. So the context is that you're publicly exposing a CiviCRM profile that contains the Current Employer field? According to the extension docs (https://github.com/TechToThePeople/publicautocomplete.git), the setting `require_match`, if TRUE, will require the user to enter an existing organization, thus preventing creation of a new organization. If you set that to FALSE, you should be able to enter a new org name and CiviCRM will use that name to create a new org; it won't have a "new" button, you just type in the org name.  Have you tried that? Am I getting the context right?

Comment: Thanks Twomice, that's exactly correct. Set to FALSE seems to re-open the door to the misspellings and typos  tho  if I am understanding.Too tricky for us to customize it to function as Current Employer field does when logged in as admin?  We are also attempting to restrict group display access in the auto-complete, from the admin end, i.e. restrict to a known list of employers already in a group.

Answer (score 2):

The issue could be that you have to set the "access AJAX API" permission for the relevant roles

Comment: Ok Pete we will check and update thank you H

Comment: Update  - we added https://civicrm.org/extensions/populate-employer-anonymous-users -  and we're trying different things as well for the advanced search, so that it suggests names similar to nearly every other field to ease administrative searches. H